# Form control required dependendo da seleção de outro form control angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Tenho o seguinte mat-checkbox:

```
<mat-checkbox formControlName="formControlIdentificador" color="primary" class="correcaoClasseCheck" labelPosition="before"></mat-checkbox>

<input formControlName="formControlNomeIdentificador" matInput placeholder="Qual era o nome no identificador?">
```

O segundo input (formControlNomeIdentificador) deve ser required se o checkbox for selecionado. Como posso fazer isso?

Esse é meu form builder:

```
    this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({

    formControlIdentificador: new FormControl('', [
    ]),

    formControlNomeIdentificador: new FormControl('', [
    ])

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu tentaria uma dessas 2 formas:
primeira:

```
<input formControlName="formControlNomeIdentificador" matInput placeholder="Qual era o nome no identificador?" [required]="secondFormGroup.get('formControlIdentificador').value">
```

Ou:

```
<input formControlName="formControlNomeIdentificador" matInput placeholder="Qual era o nome no identificador?" [required]="!secondFormGroup.valid">
```